# Kenwood TH-D72A and AO-91/92

Tags: satellites, ht, kenwood, tone-squelch

I got a Kenwood HT and using it with the Elk Antenna

On the radio, there is Tone and I set it to 67 Hz. I wasn’t able to break thru to the satellite and had it in Full Duplex mode. I can hear everyone on the satellite very well and the Signal meter was high.

Is there another setting other than Tone to set?

On my Baofeng, I used to set CTCSS and that is what the sites call for AO-91/92.

Comment: Hello Brian, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com! Please consider taking [the tour](http://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help pages](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help) to get the most from the site. ▪ Can we assume that your Baofeng can access the satellite with that Elk antenna? Also, does the Kenwood  have CTCSS?

Comment: [TH-D72A website](https://www.kenwood.com/usa/com/amateur/th-d72a/)

Comment: @Mike Waters: Yes, it has Tone and CTCSS and DCS. Not sure which to use. Baofeng only has CTCSS. AMSAT website says to set PL tone. So terms appear to be used interchangeably

Comment: This might be crazy, but were you on the TX band when you attempted to TX? You should have continued to hear the downlink of you were. Sinfulness it is the simple things. Also, if it was during the last few days, you could have been doing everything correctly but being stomped out by stronger stations. I assume you are just starting out with satellites, if this is correct, try to get on a pass late at night when there are fewer people on. Makes it easier to get into the birds.

Comment: @wag: It turns out that I am supposed to use Tone for the TH-D72A. I finally made it on tonight at least once! The person responded with my grid only but I was the only one just before with my grid and I could hear myself in my ear so I knew it was working. I grabbed an earpiece and mic from my Baofeng and used that, then also ordered a Heil HTH-K which came highly recommended online. The pass I tried tonight was at 2222. I tried one earlier in the day and failed because I didn’t realize how much feedback I was introducing by being so close to the mic. Baofeng headset and mic worked OK for now

Comment: Brian, if you put that comment in an answer, then others with the same problem can benefit from it. Comments are not searchable. You can even mark an answer to your own question as accepted for extra points! Glad to hear you solved it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This might be crazy, but you were on the TX band when you attempted to TX? You should have continued to hear the downlink of you were. Sinfulness it is the simple things.

Also, if it was during the last few days, you could have been doing everything correctly but being stomped out by stronger stations.  I assume you are just starting out with satellites, if this is correct, try to get on a pass late at night when there are fewer people on. Makes it easier to get into the birds.